# Неправильно работает функция date()

Tags: дата, php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
function convertSec($time) {
  $exp = explode(':', $time);
  if ( count($exp) == 3 ) {
    return (($exp[0] * 60) * 60) + ($exp[1] * 60) + $exp[2];
  }
  if ( count($exp) == 2 ) {
    return ($exp[0] * 60) + $exp[1];
  }
}
a::b(convertSec('5:43:25') . ' ' . '5:43:25' . ' ' . date('H:i:s', convertSec('5:43:25')));
a::b(convertSec('43:25') . ' ' . '43:25' . ' ' . date('i:s', convertSec('43:25')));
a::b(convertSec('0:25') . ' ' . '0:25' . ' ' . date('i:s', convertSec('0:25')));
```

**Результат:**

> 20605 5:43:25 08:43:25 <- тут косяк, не правильный час
>
> 2605 43:25 43:25
>
> 25 0:25 00:25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция **date()** работает согласно часовому поясу. По умолчанию это либо часовой пояс из настроек локали сервера, либо из php.ini. Если у Вас PHP >= 5.1, то используйте функцию **date_default_timezone_set()** для установки нужного часового пояса, если он Вам действительно нужен. Аналогично функция **mktime()** работает с часовым посом.

А вот функции **gmdate()** и gmmktime() всегда работают с GMT (оно же UTC или +00:00).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Irkutsk');
echo date('H:i:s P'); // 20:26:35 +09:00
echo gmdate('H:i:s P'); // 11:26:35 +00:00
```

Так-то =)